# Column Header - how to set bottom border thickness > 1

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, material-design-in-xaml

I can set the DataGridColumnHeader BorderThickness (Bottom) > 1 but all that displays is a 1px line.  Not what I want.   Is this a bug?
Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter  Property="BorderThickness"      Value="0, 0, 0, 8"       />
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing the gridlines with the border? This works for me... although I also have to set the BorderBrush to something since it appears to be either transparent or same as the Background by default.

Comment: setting the BorderBrush seems to be working `<Setter  Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Black"/>`